# Relationship between derivative of $f$ and inverse of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

1. Let $f :  \Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^m$ be a function, and let the derivative matrix of $f$ be $Df$. If $Df$ is invertible at point $a\in\Bbb R^m$, then $f$ is invertible in at least one neighbourhood of $a$.
2. If $Df$ is not invertible, then $f$ is not invertible in at least one neighbourhood of $a$.

Are these statements true? 
 Please explain with examples of functions
only for
m grater than or  equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

I think (1) is correct. But (2) is incorrect. Consider $f(x)=x^3$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Point (1) is the inverse function theorem. I won't attempt to prove it here.

Point (2) is false. $f(x) = x^3$ has zero derivative at zero but is an invertible function. But it does not have a differentiable inverse. If it has
differentiable inverse then the derivative must be non-zero
since $f \circ g = I$ implies that 
$$
Df \circ Dg = I. 
$$

For an example from $R^n$ to $R^n$ take the same function in the first coordinate and make it the identity in the other coordinates. Or make it cubing in every coordinate. Or make it cubing in a subset of coordinates.

Comment: Can you give me an example   of function  from R ^2 to R^2